# node express server doesnt respond on ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, cors

I am new to node.js and got stuck on cors problem. I am sending client ajax get request from one express server to another, but at least I am not able to get response from `app.all('*', function(req, res, next){console.log("request: "+req)})` 
GET request looks something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8082/request'
});
```

I was also setting headers in ajax with:

```
'beforeSend : function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1000');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '*')},
```

...or setting cors module in node.js:

```
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*',cors(),function(){
console.log("preflight")
});
```

In both firefox and chrome, I received no response (in chrome I got `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` )
When running node servers locally on my PC, everything works. Also curl command works fine.
Is there a chance, this is a problem with hosting/ports or am I still missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow CORS in Express/NodeJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-nodejs)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to set the CORS headers on your $ajax call, as those headers are required by the browser in the HTTP *Response* header.

For cross domain AJAX, make sure you set the `crossDomain` flag on the $ajax option:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: payload,
  dataType: 'json',
  crossDomain: true
})
```

A clean way to handle CORS requests in your express endpoints would be to create a middleware that you add to express routes that respond to cross origin requests:

**cors.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');  
  next();
};
```

Then make sure you add the middleware to the express endpoint:

```
app.post(url, cors, function(req, res) {
});
```

Comment: okey, i finally realised, that my problem was in setting url adresses of server. I replaced all my "localhost" with real domain name, set cors module in node.js and everything worked. Thank you once again for your time and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and solved with this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});
```